# OCaml open only certain values/types from module

Tags: ocaml

Does OCaml have an equivalent (possibly involving a camlp4 directive) of

`from module import value1, value2` in Python or

`use Module qw[value1 value2];` in Perl ?

I'd like to be able to write something like

`open Ctypes (@->), string;;` or `open Ctypes ((@->), string);;`

instead of

```
let (@->) = Ctypes.(@->);;
let string = Ctypes.string;;
```

Comment: maybe check out [local opens](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec224)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest is:

```
let value1, value2 = Module.(value1, value2)
```

For this very reason, open statements are most of the time evil (especially at the top level).

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is no such *partial* module opening like what you described.

- If your modules have no naming conflict, then it's simple enough to just use `open Ctypes`
- Otherwise, you can shorten the module name by

  ```
  module CT = Ctypes

  (* and then just call CT.some_function instead of Ctypes.some_function *)
  ```
- Your solutions is quite a neat one, but be careful that the name `string` may override the primitive type `string` of OCaml.

  ```
  let (@->) = Ctypes.(@->);;
  let string = Ctypes.string;;  (* override the type string *)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`cppo` and the C preprocessor since C99 both have the ability to process variadic macros.

This means that you can hide mookid's tuple assignment behind a macro to avoid repeating yourself.

```
#define USE_FROM(MODULE, ...) \
  let ( __VA_ARGS__ ) = (MODULE . ( __VA_ARGS__ )) ;;

USE_FROM(Printf, printf, sprintf, eprintf);;

let main = begin
  Printf.printf "%s\n" "a"
end
```

It's also possible to use a non-variadic macro by providing the arguments as a comma-delimited list surrounded by parentheses.

```
#define USE_FROM(MODULE, STUFF) \
  let ( STUFF ) = (MODULE . ( STUFF )) ;;

USE_FROM(Printf, (printf, sprintf, eprintf));;

let main = begin
  Printf.printf "%s\n" "a"
end
```